# Trap representation for structures

Tags: c, struct, language-lawyer

I'd like to understand the trap representation concept in details. The definition is pretty clear `Section 3.19.4`:

> an object representation that need not represent a value of the object
>   type

Okay, I'd like to try it by some examples.

```
struct test_t{
    uint64_t member;
};

struct test_t *test_ptr = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
struct test_t = *test_ptr; //1
```

I don't think that `//1` causes UB here, because `Section 6.2.6.1`:

> If the stored value of an object has such a representation and is read
>   by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the
>   behavior is undefined.

but

> The value of a structure or union object is never a trap
>   representation, even though the value of a member of the structure or
>   union object may be a trap representation.

I think UB will be caused by something like

```
printf("Test.member = %lu\n", test.member);
```

But I'm not sure how to prove that in such a case the representation of `member` is a trap.

Comment: It's UB, but not because of any possible trap-representations. Instead it's UB because you access memory out of bounds, you read memory that doesn't belong to you. And that happens at `//1`.

Comment: A trap representation is only possible when the object has bits that aren't used for value representation. Fixed width unsigned integer types use all of their bits for value representation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So can you give an example of trap representation of a member of a structure?

Comment: @StoryTeller But `*test_ptr` is an `lvalue` and the value of a structure is never a trap. Why is this UB? Could you give some reference?

Comment: You can't really have a trap-representation of a whole structure, instead you can have it in individual members. And as mentioned by @StoryTeller all values of an fixed-width unsigned integer (on a binary computer) are really valid, so there can't be any trap-representations.

Comment: @SomeName - Reference to what? To this being UB? That's the out of bounds access, which I hope you don't need convincing is UB. There is no possibility of trap representations in your code, that's not the root of the UB.

Comment: `struct test_t = *test_ptr; //1` is not even valid code: "error: expected identifier or '(' before '=' token".  Did you mean something like `struct test_t foo = *test_ptr; //1`?

Comment: Code like `uint64_t member; ... printf("Test.member = %lu\n", test.member);`  unnecessarily adds confusion as `"lu"` is not certainly the matching print specifier for `uint64_t`, thus making the `printf("Test.member = %lu\n", test.member);` UB right there.  Better to code with `"%" PRIu64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`member` has no trap representations, because `uint64_t` has no trap representations.

> **7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types**
>
> [2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20) The typedef name uint*N*_t designates an unsigned integer type
>   with width *N* and no padding bits. Thus, uint24_t denotes such an
>   unsigned integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits.

No padding bits. And from the following section we learn:

> **6.2.6.2 Integer types**
>
> [1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p1) For unsigned integer types other than unsigned char, the bits
>   of the object representation shall be divided into two groups: value
>   bits and padding bits (there need not be any of the latter). If there
>   are N value bits, each bit shall represent a different power of 2
>   between 1 and 2<sup>N - 1</sup>, so that objects of that type shall be
>   capable of representing values from 0 to 2<sup>N</sup>  - 1 using a
>   pure binary representation; this shall be known as the value
>   representation. The values of any padding bits are
>   unspecified.<sup>53)</sup>

Where note 53, despite being non-normative, tells us that those padding bits (if they exist) can be used to trap:

> <sub>[53)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note53) Some combinations of padding bits might generate trap
>   representations, for example, if one padding bit is a parity bit.
>   Regardless, no arithmetic operation on valid values can generate a
>   trap representation other than as part of an exceptional condition
>   such as an overflow, and this cannot occur with unsigned types. All
>   other combinations of padding bits are alternative object
>   representations of the value specified by the value bits.</sub>

While value bits can never hold a pattern that is illegal.

So you cannot produce a trap representation of `uint64_t` in a well-formed program. Mind you, that your program has UB due to the out of bounds access, but that is not caused by possibility of trap representations. It's undefined all on its own.

Comment: Saying quicker the only types used nowadays which have the trap representation are float numbers and enum types.

Comment: I misunderstood the trap-representation concept... Thanks.